# why double if statement in java return empty search in array

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote the code below in java to compare and return a searhKey in the array, but is not returning anything in the array

```
package arraytest;

public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int objType[] = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        int arrSize;
        int searchKey = 0;

        objType[0] = 20;
        objType[1] = 15;
        objType[2] = 10;
        objType[3] = 11;
        objType[4] = 17;
        arrSize = 5;

        for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
            System.out.println(objType[i]);
        }

        searchItem(objType, searchKey, arrSize);
    }

    public static void searchItem(int objType[], int searchKey, int arrSize) {
        int i = 0, temp = 10;
        for (int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++)
            if (objType[i] == temp) {
                searchKey = temp;
                if (j == arrSize)
                    System.out.println("Search key not found");
                System.out.println("found search key " + searchKey);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are your brackets?

Comment: As to what Yassin is asking, its usually a good idea to ALWAYS use brackets with your statements even if they are only controlling a single statement. It makes debugging far easier and makes following your control flow much easier

Comment: Just so you don't get confused, both of the above commenters are talking about braces. And one of the problem is that you have `objType[i]` but never incrementing `i` Use `objType[j]`

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense to me right now: why are you using `i` here `objType[i] == temp` which is always 0, instead of `j`? And why are you using `temp` there instead of `searchKey`?

Comment: And why do you set arraysize explicitely? And why do you define the first i variable out of the loop? And why do you even provide the arraysize to the method? And why do you print out that the search key is not found when you still matched the key? Sorry, couldn't hold on to ask like this ;)

Comment: And `j == arrSize` is never true inside the loop’s body when its precondition is `j < arrSize`…

Comment: bobbel. the best way to help others is to consider them as novice not as expert like you, @bobbel, i am first timer in java  and right now the detail comments you made solve much problem i have been battling with. thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

You're iterating on `j` but comparing using `i`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++)
            if (objType[i] == temp) {
```

Also you pass searchKey as parameter but use it as a temporary variable for output, which doesn't make much sense.

Make sure you do want to pass arrSize since you can use `objType.length` or enhanced `for` (it's still OK if you want to search part of the array, but the name is misleading then, but I doubt that was your intention)

That could be:

```
 public static void searchItem(int arr[], int searchKey) {
     int found = 0;
     for (int item : arr) {
         if (item == searchKey) {
              System.out.println("found search key " + searchKey);
              found ++;             
        }    
    }
    if (found == 0) System.out.println("Search key not found");
 }
```

You may want to break, however, if the key was found, or return the number of found keys. This way the method only produces output.

Comment: So, you're printing for a lot of items "Search key not found"?

Answer (score 2):

This might be one plausible solution (thanks to comments from @Tom, and I have tested the code):

```
package arraytest;

public class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int objType[] = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        int arrSize;
        int searchKey = 10;

        objType[0] = 20;
        objType[1] = 15;
        objType[2] = 10;
        objType[3] = 11;
        objType[4] = 17;
        arrSize = 5;

        for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
            System.out.println(objType[i]);
        }

        searchItem(objType, searchKey, arrSize);
    }

    public static void searchItem(int objType[], int searchKey, int arrSize) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++) {
            if (objType[j] == searchKey) {
                System.out.println("found search key " + searchKey);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Search key not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: you don't need the `found` variable. When you return after printing "found ... bla bla", then you only reach "not found" if it really couldn't be found.

Comment: @Tom That's right! However, I added `found` variable because I was considering the situation that there are multiple matches in the array (e.g., objType[0] = 10 and objType[1] = 10, while searchKey = 10). If we return after printing "found...", then the rest matches won't be found. Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, if the user needs that depends on how one likes to use it. If one want to check how many items match a certain key, then this would be suitable, but if one will just check if there is at least one match, then it is doing to much. But we don't know how OP want's to use the method .... :D.

Comment: @Tom I can't agree more with you :-D

Comment: Wow, you understood that mess in the first sentence? That happens if you rewrite if several times and forget to delete the "old stuff" :D. So the part *"if the user needs"* doesn't belong there :D.

Comment: @Tom Yes I guess that's what you mean :-P

Comment: Thank you very much @Tsung-Ting Kuo. problem solved, but is it necessary to use the boolean and found variable? i only need to print one key that matches the searchKey. thank a lot

Comment: @Sirmee In this case then Tom's suggestion is correct. I have edited my answer so now the `found` variable is removed. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your nested if statement will never get hit:

```
if (j == arrSize)
    System.out.println("Search key not found");
```

This is because of your foor loop `for (int j = 0; j < arrSize; j++)` which means that if `j == arrSize` the loop will exit and nothing inside will be run. You want to put your if statement outside your for loop, and change `j` to `i`:

```
int i = 0, temp = 10;
for (i = 0; i < arrSize; i++) {
    if (objType[i] == temp) {
        searchKey = temp;
        System.out.println("found search key " + searchKey);
        break;
    }
}

if (i == arrSize) {
    System.out.println("Search key not found");
}
```

Comment: Please recheck your last `if` ;P.

Comment: @Raheel Another thing I missed, proves it's too early to be programming :P. Fixed it

Comment: @Raheel Instead of messing with his code you should explain why you think that there is still a bug in there. (Spoiler alert: you're wrong).